# Is it possible for a C method not be able to be included in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

I know I can include C methods inside a C++ project using the `extern "C"` thing. But lets us now suppose that I'm thinking in creating a C++ project that would use quite a lot of C methods coming from both libraries made by me as well as libraries made by other people/companies whose developing details and compilation specifications I'm simply not aware of.

Is it possible that some of this methods of C libraries, with unknown compilation and configuration details, could not be included in my C++ project with `extern "C"`? Or are all C methods necessarily 100% compatible with C++ code insofar `extern "C"` is used?

Comment: Btw, C has "functions", not "methods".

Comment: If the external libraries are built from C source, then the symbols already are in the correct format inside the binary libraries. Then you need `extern "C"` around the function *declarations* the *header* files.

Comment: The only problem that occurs to me is that if you have C functions whose names are C++ reserved words, e.g. `class()` or `new()`. Otherwise it should all just work as expected.

Comment: "with unknown compilation and configuration details"? No.  But if you could ensure that the function was declared `static`, then yes, the linker would not be able to link against it.

Comment: @unwind are you sure? The definition of function in math is "one or more inputs that lead to a unique result" (famous y(x)), so there is no such thing as a function that returns `void`, and yet one can create > methods < in C that do return void - so, they are not functions :) "All functions are methods but not all methods, particularly those who return 'void', are functions"

Comment: @Momergil Who's talking about math?

Comment: @Momergil: We're talking about C and C++, not mathematics. Those languages have their own concept of a "function", and no concept of a "method".

Comment: @unwind and Mike, AFAIRemember (from my first C and C++ classes 5 years ago), the meaning of the name "function" used in this contexts do comes from Math :) I remember specially that my C++ professor insisted in calling them "methods" when everybody in the class would talk "functions". Of course, I really might have misinterpreted something...

Comment: @Momergil How do you feel about `int` variables in C and C++ only supporting a limited number of bits, even though the type name is clearly a short form of "integer"? :)

Comment: @unwind and Mike, of course, I'm using the word "method" as a literal translation from the Portuguese "método" (and "function" for "função"), since this was the word used by my professors. Maybe its my translation that is actually problematic...

Comment: @unwind good point! xD

Comment: The term used in the C++ standard is *function.* C++ does not use the term "method" at all - even the things inside classes are called member *functions.*

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that some of the functions exported by C use names that collide with C++ keywords.  You wouldn't be able to declare those using `extern "C"`.

Functions exported by assembler could even use names that conflict with C keywords.

Those and functions declared static can still be called via function pointer, as long as the library gives you a way to get one.

Headers might not be parse-able in C++ mode for the same reasons -- things like the `restrict` keyword.

Other than naming issues, C++ has full support for the C calling convention.  That's what `extern "C"` is all about.

Answer (score 2):

C has constructs for interfaces that are not compatible with C++, in particular variable length arrays. In modern C you would write

```
void matMult(size_t n, size_t k, size_t m, double A[n][k], double B[k][m], double C[n][m]);
```

this interface can not be included as such in C++ compilation units.

Comment: yeah, that's quite truth; just tested it here in one of my C++ projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although rather unlikely, one possible issue that might arise with `extern "C"` in-place is when a function pointer declared `extern "C"` points to a C++ function that is not declared `extern "C"`. See the last part of this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) for more details.

Comment: If a C function takes a function pointer as an argument, some compilers might choke if you feed it a pointer to a C++ function. I remember reading it somewhere.

Comment: To be a decent answer, this should be more precise and not only refer to hearsay.

Comment: @JensGustedt Good point, thanks. I've included the reference.